# get all attributes from all tags in page [Beautiful soup]

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get all attributes of every tag in a html page by beautiful soup
in an array

for example I have a html page
I want all tags attributes in a string array

```
<div att0="content1">
<a href="link1">link data</a>
</div>
```

result would be:
[content1, link1]

Comment: What a beautiful example.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Find all elements and get the attributes from [`.attrs` attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes):

```
attrs = []
for elm in soup():  # soup() is equivalent to soup.find_all()
    attrs += list(elm.attrs.values())

print(attrs)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <div att0="content1">
... <a href="link1">link data</a>
... </div>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
>>> 
>>> attrs = []
>>> for elm in soup():
...     attrs += list(elm.attrs.values())
... 
>>> print(attrs)
['content1', 'link1']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import bs4

html = '''
<div att0="content1">
<a href="link1">link data</a>
</div>
<div att0="content1">
<a href="link1">link data</a>
</div>
<div att0="content1">
<a href="link1">link data</a>
</div>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div', att0=True):
    out = [div['att0'], div.a['href']]
    print(out)
```

out:

```
['content1', 'link1']
['content1', 'link1']
['content1', 'link1']
```

Comment: I mean every tag, div and a were just examples

Comment: @reza why don't you post all tag in the question?

Comment: no, there is no certain tag. every tag in html, in any page and url